# AS3, create more same function in for loop mehod

Tags: function, actionscript-3, loops, for-loop, flash-cs5

I try to make some function in for loop method, but it says "Symbol 'myInstanceMovieClip', Layer 'as', Frame 31, Line 29    1084: Syntax error: expecting leftparen before leftbracket."
Here my code:

```
for(var i:int=0; i < btnhairmc.length; i++){
   btnhairmc[i].buttonMode=true;
   btnhairmc[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay[i]);
   function goPlay[i](m:MouseEvent):void{
      trace("btnhair[i]_mc <= clicked");
   }
}
```

Where's my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function name: `goPlay[i]` is not valid, should be only `goPlay`

You can adjust your code:

```
for (var i:int=0; i < btnhairmc.length; i++) {
   btnhairmc[i].buttonMode=true;
   btnhairmc[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay);
   function goPlay(m:MouseEvent):void {
      trace("btnhair["+i+"]_mc <= clicked");
   }
}
```

Or

```
for (var i: int = 0; i < btnhairmc.length; i++) {
    btnhairmc[i].buttonMode = true;
    btnhairmc[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (event: MouseEvent): void {
        trace("btnhair[" + i + "]_mc <= clicked");
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
for (var i:int=0; i < btnhairmc.length; i++) {
   btnhairmc[i].buttonMode=true;
   btnhairmc[i].name="button-"+i;
   btnhairmc[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay);
}

function goPlay(e:MouseEvent) : void {
    trace(e.target.name);
    //or maybe you need
    trace(e.currentTarget.name);
    trace('Button' + e.target.name + 'was clicked!');
}
```

With **e.target** or **e.currentTarget** you will know which button was pressed

Hope this helps.